# How to order a list of states for a route

Tags: gis

I'm trying to take a list of states that I currently get in alphabetical order, and sort them by route order.

As an example: A route starts in Colorado and ends in Washington and I know that it goes through Oregon, Idaho, Utah, and Wyoming ( eg http://goo.gl/maps/j6tyu )

Alphabetically the route would be (CO, ID, OR, UT, WA, WY), the route order would be (CO, WY, UT, ID, OR, WA)

Is it possible to calculate the route order by just knowing which states touch which other states, or what other information would I need to have? Are there suggested reading links that could help me

I also actually have the miles traveled in each state if that helps. 
(
CO = 90
, ID = 275
, OR = 372
, UT = 149
, WA = 8
, WY = 368
)

Comment: a) What platform are you going to use - GIS software, database query, programming language? b) Do you know, what is first state in the route?

Comment: It seems to be quite tricky task and in some cases, you can't get singular result. For example, route may be: 
 Alabama-Tennesse-Mississippi-Arkansas or Alabama-Mississippi-Tennesse-Arkansas. Another example: when you have Alabama, Tennesse, Mississippi, you can't tell, from which state route starts and where it ends.

Comment: @user1702401, I'm developing in php, and as I mentioned in the post both the start and end points are known. I'm starting to think that this is not possible given just adjacency.

Comment: If you know both start and end, this task is way simpler. You could google for list of states, where each state has it's neighbours (ie Florida: Georgia, Alabama), and write search routine in PHP (probably recursive).

Comment: This list should help: http://theincidentaleconomist.com/wordpress/list-of-neighboring-states-with-stata-code/ NB pay attention to AK and HI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's interesting problem, I wrote small JS script just for fun: http://jsfiddle.net/Ufbbt/

```
var from = 'CO';
var to = 'WY';
var thru = ['ID', 'OR', 'UT', 'WA'];

var globalCount = 0;

var doStuff = function(currState, states, str) {

    if (states.length == 0) {
        if (inArray(to, statesDesc[currState])) {
            console.log(str + '->' + to);
            globalCount++;
        }
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0, len = states.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (inArray(states[i], statesDesc[currState])) {
            var newStates = states.slice(0); // clone original array
            var newCurrState = newStates.splice(i, 1)[0];
            doStuff(newCurrState, newStates, str + '->' + newCurrState);
        }
    }
}

var inArray = function(what, where) {
    for (var i = 0, len = where.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (what == where[i]) 
            return true;
    }
    return false;   
}

// Now, initial execute
doStuff(from, thru, from);
console.log(globalCount + ' route(s) found');

var statesDesc = {
    AK: ['WA'],
    AL: ['TN','GA','FL','MS'],
    AR: ['MO','TN','MS','LA','TX','OK'],
    AZ: ['UT','CO','NM','CA','NV'],
    CA: ['OR','NV','AZ','HI'],
    CO: ['WY','NE','KS','OK','NM','AZ','UT'],
    CT: ['MA','RI','NY'],
    DC: ['MD','VA'],
    DE: ['PA','NJ','MD'],
    FL: ['GA','AL'],
    GA: ['NC','SC','FL','AL','TN'],
    HI: ['CA'],
    IA: ['MN','WI','IL','MO','NE','SD'],
    ID: ['MT','WY','UT','NV','OR','WA'],
    IL: ['WI','IN','KY','MO','IA'],
    IN: ['MI','OH','KY','IL'],
    KS: ['NE','MO','OK','CO'],
    KY: ['OH','WV','VA','TN','MO','IL','IN'],
    LA: ['AR','MS','TX'],
    MA: ['NH','RI','CT','NY','VT'],
    MD: ['PA','DE','DC','VA','WV'],
    ME: ['NH'],
    MI: ['OH','IN','WI'],
    MN: ['WI','IA','SD','ND'],
    MO: ['IA','IL','KY','TN','AR','OK','KS','NE'],
    MS: ['TN','AL','LA','AR'],
    MT: ['ND','SD','WY','ID'],
    NC: ['VA','SC','GA','TN'],
    ND: ['MN','SD','MT'],
    NE: ['SD','IA','MO','KS','CO','WY'],
    NH: ['ME','MA','VT'],
    NJ: ['NY','DE','PA'],
    NM: ['CO','OK','TX','AZ','UT'],
    NV: ['ID','UT','AZ','CA','OR'],
    NY: ['VT','MA','CT','NJ','PA'],
    OH: ['PA','WV','KY','IN','MI'],
    OK: ['KS','MO','AR','TX','NM','CO'],
    OR: ['WA','ID','NV','CA'],
    PA: ['NY','NJ','DE','MD','WV','OH'],
    RI: ['MA','CT'],
    SC: ['NC','GA'],
    SD: ['ND','MN','IA','NE','WY','MT'],
    TN: ['KY','VA','NC','GA','AL','MS','AR','MO'],
    TX: ['OK','AR','LA','NM'],
    UT: ['ID','WY','CO','NM','AZ','NV'],
    VA: ['MD','DC','NC','TN','KY','WV'],
    VT: ['NH','MA','NY'],
    WA: ['AK','ID','OR'],
    WI: ['MI','IL','IA','MN'],
    WV: ['PA','MD','VA','KY','OH'],
    WY: ['MT','SD','NE','CO','UT','ID']
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but I think that this is still a useful response.